# Symfony ManyToMany relationship working partially

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony

I am stuck at a problem that in theory sounds pretty straight forward but in Symfony I am not able to implement it so I am hoping anyone here can push me in right direction.

I will explain first what I am trying to do and let you know how far did I get trying to achieve this. Just for your information I am using Symfony 3.0

**What I am trying to do**

1. I have two Entity 'Post' and 'Category' and they are linked
   together in ManytoMany relationship bidirectional.
2. When I am creating a new post, I want to assign it a category which should be checkboxes and linked with Category Entity
3. After saving the post, when I edit it the category checkboxes should appear as selected (those categories that are assigned to the post)

**What I have done so far**

Entity are already linked and the relationship seems to be working fine because when i save the post it gets saved and the join table of category and posts gets updated as well with post id and category id. If i select multiple categories they get saved as well in the join table.

**What i am stuck at**

When I edit the post, the post data appears fine but the category check boxes do not appear as selected and this is where i need your help.

**How i created the form.**

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it but it seems to be working, so if i am wrong somewhere and not doing it right the symfony way please do correct me.

This is manyTomany from `post.orm.yml`

```
manyToMany:
    categories:
        targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\Category
        inversedBy: posts
        joinTable:
            name: posts_categories
            joinColumns:
                post_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                category_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
        cascade:  ["persist"]
```

This is manyTomany from `category.orm.yml`

```
manyToMany:
    posts:
        targetEntity: MyBundle\Entity\Post
        mappedBy: categories
        joinTable:
            name: posts_categories
            joinColumns:
                post_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                category_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

The `CategoryType` is straight forward

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Category'
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is the `PostType`, this is where i have doubt if i have done it right.

```
class PostType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Category',
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'multiple'     => true,
                    'expanded'     => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    ))
            ->add('categories', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => CategoryType::class,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ));;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver

     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(

            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Post'
        ));
    }
}
```

In order for me to display the already created categories i created a new property in `Post` entity with name `Category` which in the `PostType` is pulling the categories from `Category` Entity.

Then there is `categories` CollectionType as well. When the form is submitted i use the loop to add categories in the join table.

```
    $catagories = $form->get('category')->getData();
    foreach ($catagories as $cat) {
        $post->getCategories()->add($cat);
    }
```

Doing this does save the information in join table but when I edit it the checkboxes do not appear as selected.

Another strange thing I noticed if i remove the `->add('categories', CollectionType::class` from the `PostType` I get the following error which is really weird because these values DONT exist in the table so i am not sure why it says they are duplicate

```
posts_categories (post_id, category_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [30, 1]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '30-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me what i am doing wrong here.

UPDATE: Just adding an image to show that post_id and category_id are being saved in join table
[image]

Comment: You don't need the joinTable in the mappedBy side. But it does not solve your problem.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella you are correct, i just added that to see if that solves it but you are right it does not :)

Comment: Check your database join table.  I think you will find that while the post ids are set the category ids are not.

Comment: @Cerad the `post_id` and `category_id` are both being saved. I updated my question and added a screenshot of the join table to demonstrate that ids are being saved from both entity

Comment: Am I understand right - everything is o.k. when you create new post, add some categories and save? Things gone bad when you edit already saved post and click to save again (and in both cases when yes or no are you manipulating with categories)?

Comment: @JanRydrych when i save the post, it works fine, post data is saved and categories are saved too. But when i edit it the categories are not selected by default.

Comment: Did you check the IDs of both entites in join table? Are they correct?

Comment: @JanRydrych yes they are correct, i can post screenshots if you want

Comment: is my understanding right that symfony will mark the checkbox if the category exist or my assumption is wrong?

Comment: IMHO in your particular case no. You have to use data transformer. Check this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#harder-example-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity

Comment: Thanks for the tip, are you sure doie this will mark the check box as selected for linked categories?

Comment: @JanRydrych just thought of letting you know that i managed to solve the problem and the data transformer was not required to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this is what I found out.

IF the relationship is set to manyToMany the `EntityType` will render as checkboxes as long as `multiple` and `expanded` is set to `true`. So all i had to do was

1. Get rid of the foreach loop i was using in my controller
2. Clean up the `PostType` to as following

> ```
> class PostType extends AbstractType
> {
>
> public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
> {
>     $builder
>         ->add('title')
>         ->add('description')
>         ->add('categories', EntityType::class, array(
>                 'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Category',
>                 'choice_label' => 'name',
>                 'multiple'     => true,
>                 'expanded'     => true,
>                 'by_reference' => false,
>                 ));
> }
>
> public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
> {
>     $resolver->setDefaults(array(
>
>         'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Post'
>     ));
> }
> }
> ```

Thats it, now I can still save the `category_id` and `post_id` in the join table, and on edit i can see the categories selected by default.